# Is there any way to make the login screens on Ventura 13.6.1 and Sonoma 14.0 look the same?

Tags: macos

I use Continuity between two iMacs.  Physically of course they are identical, but one is slightly older and just out of range I suppose for the Sonoma update.  For 90% of the functionality I use, on the older Mac throughout my workday, it's visually and interactively identical.  I'm ok with Settings and Widgets and other parts that aren't so visible and regularly used being different, but one change is a source of constant annoyance.  Login and Unlock.  Despite setting the same backgrounds on both machines, they are starkly different at startup and when unlocking after screen savers have activated.  The avatar and password entry are located in the center of the screen on Ventura and Sonoma kicked them to the bottom and presents the time in large digits up top.

Is there a way to configure the systems to look identical here, to have some consistency?  I can't see how there is any logical or performance impact by breaking this uniform interface element.  Change for the sake of change.  I don't even mind if it means taking the clock away from the Sonoma system.  I'd just like them to look the same.  Likewise, eventually I'll upgrade perhaps to a Mac Studio, but older machines will remain relegated to particular tasks and services.  So if it means having a older login dialog on all, it just doesn't matter that much, but the consistency is important.